# The GPS updates won't turn off after closing application

Tags: android, gps, updates, geo

I have created an application that has a 'geolocation' feature responsible for spotting a user on the Google map like many other applicatons. I used "LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER" to locate the user and at the same time I instantiate and start "MyLocationOverlay" (in the `onLocationChanged()` method) to get the location. Because of the second one, the GPS turns on (blinking on the top) which is OK.

The problem is, after the application is closed (back button or through task manager), the GPS feature is still hanging there, trying to get the updates.

How to turn it off after the user leaves the activity? I tried suggestions from here and other forums like putting `locationManager.removeUpdates(this);` and `locationManager.removeUpdates(mMyLocationOverlay);` within the methods `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`. The method `OnPause` looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() { 
  super.onPause(); 
  locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  locationManager.removeUpdates(mMyLocationOverlay);
}
```

('this' references my class that implements LocationListener)

Please, can someone help me to turn off GPS updates after leaving the activity (it's a class that extends MapActivity) but not turn off the GPS feature on the phone itself?

Interesting thing is that when I remove the part with MyLocationOverlay, GPS will not start of course and therefore no problem. So I'm pretty sure that `mMyLocationOverlay` is the listener that "won't stop" and producing a problem.

Comment: "the GPS feature is still hanging there, trying to get the updates" -- and how have you determined this?

Comment: By the GPS indicator on the phone, which starts blinking when activity is started but won't stop when the user leaves activity...

Comment: If by "the phone" you mean "the emulator", that icon never goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close (or end) the application you can use

System.exit(0);

so when the application is closed, all the services you use will close.

Comment: is there a better way for it ? I used System.exit() for my every code. What should I do for better way?

Comment: You do not terminate your process. Android will terminate your process if and when it is needed. You certainly do not need to terminate your process to discontinue use of location updates.

Comment: hey irukeru, thanks for this, this actually works for me just fine! The only thing that I'm surprised with is that System.exit(0) does NOT close the entire application (which I don't want since there are other features in application besides user spotting on a map). So it behaves just like I wanted, the MapActivity is closed and GPS indicator disappears, but application is still on and ready for other features...

Comment: Of course, as CommonsWare stated, this may be not a good practice, using System.exit but this is the only solution that works for me now... If anyone has  a better suggestion, please advice... Thanks once again...

Answer (score 2):

**googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);** in onPause() solved my issue. And I'm setting that to **true** in OnCreate(). Hope this may help others.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `LocationListener` equal to `null` and re-instantiate `onResume()`

Comment: Jack, thanks for advice, I tried that but still the same, GPS indicator continues blinking. I suppose you meant MyLocationOverlay listener because it is the one that initiates the GPS updates? so I added the line 
mMyLocationOverlay=null; 
in onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy() methods but no progress on this..
Any other idea_